# Get all Kafka topics from another Docker container?

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

When running on the host, I can get all the Kafka topics with:

`docker exec broker kafka-topics --bootstrap-server broker:29092 --list`

I can't run this from within a container because I'd get `docker: not found`, even if I installed Docker in the container I don't think it'll work anyway. Also, apparently it's hard and insecure to be able to run an arbitrary command in another Docker container. How else can I get all the Kafka topics from within another Docker container? E.g. can I interface with Kafka through http?

Comment: I get `broker: command not found`, I'm running this in a container that's not `broker`

Comment: I have pasted by mistake `broker` in prev comment.  can you try run same kafka-topics command pointing to other docker -bootstrap-server server like this `kafka-topics --bootstrap-server <other-docker-host>:29092 --list`

Comment: You should be able to use any ordinary Kafka library or CLI tool – you should not need `docker exec` for "normal" interactions with containers.

Answer (score 2):

> I get `docker: not found`

That seems to imply `docker` CLI command is not installed, and has nothing to do with Kafka.

`docker` is not (typically) installed in "another container", so that explains that... You'll need to install Java and download Kafka cli tools to run `kafka-topics.sh` in any other environment, and then not use `docker exec`.

---

Otherwise, your command is "correct", but if you are using Docker Compose, you should do it like this from **your host** (change port accordingly).

```bash
docker-compose exec broker bash -c \
  "kafka-topics --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092"
```

Comment: My question is running it from another container

Comment: Yeah, like I said, 1) `docker`  command is not available. Therefore, 2) if Kafka CLI tools aren't either, then you will need to download them. 3) They also require Java, and not all containers have Java either... Your other options include using scripts in Javascript, Python, Go, Rust, etc that use Kafka client libraries. Or, download other containers like AKHQ or Conduktor that offers web GUIs and list topics (and more)